# sql for 3 table query for sales total

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables
Table A

```
geographies  
Atlanta
Miami
```

Table B

```
geographies stores  month
Atlanta     1       1
Atlanta     2       1
Atlanta     1       2
Miami       2       1
Miami       3       1
```

table C

```
Stores  months   Sales
1        1         100
1        2          50
2        1          25
3        1          10
```

how do i create a report like this

```
Geography  Month TotalSales
Atlanta     1     xxx
Atlanta     2     xxxx
Miami       1     xxxxx
```

thanks for the help

Comment: What type of DBMS implementation (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, etc.) are you using?  Also, what is your skill level with SQL?

Answer (score 0):

This query is for SQL Server, but if you change the escaping characters [] you can run it on every database.

Basically you `JOIN` all tables with the relevant columns ang `GROUP BY` montn and geography

> ```
> SELECT
> ta.[geographies],tb.[month], SUM([Sales]) total_amount
> FROM TableA ta JOIN TableB tb ON ta.[geographies] = tb.[geographies]
> JOIN TableC tc ON tc.[Stores] = tb.[Stores] AND tb.[month] = tc.[months]
> GROUP BY ta.[geographies],tb.[month]
> ```
>
> ```
> geographies | month | total_amount
> :---------- | ----: | -----------:
> Atlanta     |     1 |          125
> Atlanta     |     2 |           50
> Miami       |     1 |           35
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fde3ac6fc4f0c196ce723542ccd14734)*